# RxAndroid: Synchronously execute a observable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am starting on Rx with RxAndroid and I want to list the name of GitHub user by its API with Retrofit. Each API request brings 100 users, after I have processed all the users I want to get the next 100, but I can`t realize how to do that. Anyone could help me?

Where is some snippets of my code

The retrofit interface

```
interface GitHubService {
    @GET("/users")
    List<User> users(@Query("since") int since);
}
```

The user class

```
class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String login;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

And the onCreate method of my activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("User-Agent", "Retrofit-Sample-App");
            request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        }
    };

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .build();

    GitHubService mWebService = restAdapter.create(GitHubService.class);

    mWebService.users().flatMap(new Func1<List<User>, Observable<User>>() {
            @Override public Observable<User> call(List<User> users) {
                return Observable.from(users);
            }
        }).flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<String>>(){
            @Override public Observable<String> call(User user) {
                return Observable.just(user.getId() + ": " + user.getLogin());
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.i("TEST", "EXIT");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.i("TEST", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {
                Log.i("TEST", s);
            }
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    BehaviorSubject<Integer> pagingSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();

    // subscribe to this observable and do with data whatever you want
    Observable<List<User>> usersObservable = pagingSubject.flatMap(page -> mWebService.users(page)); 

    // fetch pages
    pagingSubject.onNext(1);
    pagingSubject.onNext(2);
```

As above, you can use Subject to pass pages that you wish to fetch. You might call pagingSubject.onNext(page) after request is complete (haven't checked how Github users request looks but you might get "since" parameter for next request in response).